# Scala/Lift check if date is correctly formatted

Tags: scala, lift

I have a date input box in my lift application, and I want to check that a user-entered date is in correct format: **dd/mm/yyyy**.

How can I write a regex check for this in scala? I've looked at pattern matching examples - but that seems over-complicated.

PS: I don't have to use regex, any other alternatives are welcome!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is ugly and (more disturbingly) non-thread-safe.  If you try to simultaneously use the same instance in 2 or more threads then expect things to blow up in a most unpleasant fashion.

JodaTime is far nicer:

```
import org.joda.time.format._
val fmt = DateTimeFormat forPattern "dd/MM/yyyy"
val input = "12/05/2009"
val output = fmt parseDateTime input
```

If it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, then the date wasn't valid.

As I suspect you'll want to know the actual date if it was valid, you may want to return an `Option[DateTime]`, with `None` if it was invalid.

```
def parseDate(input: String) = try {
  Some(fmt parseDateTime input)
} catch {
  case e: IllegalArgumentException => None
}
```

Alternatively, use an `Either` to capture the actual exception if formatting wasn't possible:

```
def parseDate(input: String) = try {
  Right(fmt parseDateTime input)
} catch {
  case e: IllegalArgumentException => Left(e)
}
```

**UPDATE**

To then use the `Either`, you have two main tactics:

map one of the two sides:

```
parseDate(input).left map (_.getMessage)
//will convert the Either[IllegalArgumentException, DateTime]
//to an Either[String, DateTime]
```

fold it:

```
parseDate(input) fold (
  _ => S.error(
    "birthdate",
    "Invalid date. Please enter date in the form dd/mm/yyyy."),
  dt => successFunc(dt)
)
```

Of course, the two can be composed:

```
parseDate(input).left map (_.getMessage) fold (
  errMsg => S.error("birthdate", errMsg), //if failure (Left by convention)
  dt => successFunc(dt) //if success (Right by convention)
)
```

Comment: Just a note that if its to be used in Lift, you're better off with Box versus Option in terms of a wrapper.  Box will allow you to store the error.

Comment: @arcticpenguin - I personally have a stong dislike of Lift's `Box` construct, and will convert them to `Option`s at the earliest opportunity when forced to accept the things by the API.  If I need to also track exceptions monadically then I'll use an `Either` in preference, not least because I can easily map the exception to a `String` or some other type for logging or presentation to the end user.

Comment: Thanks! I like it. I have it working now as "validateDate(birthdate) match {
     case Some(_) => // success
     case None =>S.error("birthdate", "Invalid date. Please enter date in the form dd/mm/yyyy.")
    }"

Comment: I still don't know what the Either is for - hehe, but I know the Option - so I went with that.

Comment: fmt = YYYY/MM/DD, input = 2015/02/34
No exception is thrown

Answer (score 2):

As user unknown has written you should use some library that knows how to handle dates correctly including days per specific month and leap years.

`SimpleDateFormat` is not very intuitive regarding rollovers of fields and initially accepts wrong dates by just rolling over the other fields. To prevent it from doing so you have to invoke `setLenient(false)` on it. Also keep in mind that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe so you need to create a new instance every time you want to use it:

```
def validate(date: String) = try {
    val df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    df.setLenient(false)
    df.parse(date)
    true
  } catch {
    case e: ParseException => false
  }
```

Alternatively you may also use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is a bit more intuitive than the Java Date APIs and offers thread-safe date formats:

```
val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")

def validate(date: String) = try {
    format.parseMillis(date)
    true
  }
  catch {
    case e: IllegalArgumentException => false
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to define the `DateTimeFormatter` instance in an object since it's thread-safe and immutable.

```
  object DateOfBirth{
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
    import scala.util.Try
    private val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
    def validate(date: String) = Try(fmt.parseDateTime(date)).isSuccess
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regex, but SimpleDateFormat (which isn't that simple, as we will see).

A regular expression which handles to allow 28 and 30 as day, but not 38, different month-lengths and leap years, might be an interesting challenge, but not for real world code.

```
val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

(I assume M as in big Month, not m as in small minute).

Now, let's start with an error:

```
scala> df.parse ("09/13/2001")                                
res255: java.util.Date = Wed Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 2002
```

hoppla - it is very tolerant, and wraps months around to the next year. But we can get it with a second formatting process:

```
scala> val sInput = "13/09/2001"
sInput: java.lang.String = 13/09/2001

scala> sInput.equals (df.format (df.parse (sInput))) 
res259: Boolean = true

scala> val sInput = "09/13/2001"                     
sInput: java.lang.String = 09/13/2001

scala> sInput.equals (df.format (df.parse (sInput))) 
res260: Boolean = false
```

I hope you aren't bound to regex, and can use it.

Comment: Oh no, I can use anything I like. I amended the question. This looks interesting, thanks!

Comment: So - are you saying that to check if it's wrong - i should match it - and the convert it back to the string?

Comment: Also - does this verify that the date is a "real" date, or only that it conforms to the general syntax. Like can I have April 31, 2011?

Answer (score 1):

from this we can validate date in string as well as we get the expected date response by parsing in the format like "dd/MM/yyyy".

```
  try {  val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
  format.parseMillis(dateInString)
  val df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
  val newDate = df.parse(dateInString)
  true
    } catch {
      case e: ParseException => false

      case e: IllegalArgumentException => false
    }
```